# Factorization of 2d Conformal blocks

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, special-functions

In 2d CFT, we usually say that the contribution of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ factorize, and then we just consider the $z$ part. In what sense is this true? For example, can the 4-point function be factorized into the form $f(z)g(\bar{z})$? What about the global conformal blocks? The conformal blocks is given in this paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.0004v2.pdf, equation 3.15, 
$$
g_{O}\left(u,v\right)\equiv g_{\Delta,l}\left(u,v\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{l}}{2^{l}}\frac{z\overline{z}}{z-\overline{z}}\left[k_{\Delta+l}\left(z\right)k_{\Delta-l-2}\left(\overline{z}\right)-\left(z\leftrightarrow\overline{z}\right)\right]
$$
$$
k_{\beta}\left(x\right)\equiv x^{\frac{\beta}{2}}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{\beta}{2},\frac{\beta}{2},\beta,x\right)
$$

$$
u=z\overline{z},v=\left(1-z\right)\left(1-\overline{z}\right)
$$
It seems to me that $g_{\Delta,l}(u,v)$ is not factorized into the form $f(z)g(\bar{z})$. I think I have some serious misunderstanding of these stuff, can anybody point out my misunderstanding?

Comment: What context do you have in mind whit factorisation? It is not true in general that everything always factorises in products of $z,z^*$

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conformal blocks you cited correspond to the 4d blocks. In that case the contributions of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ do not factorize. For the 2d conformal blocks see 2.9 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0309180. They are given by, in the notation you've used:

$\big(\frac{-1}{2}\big)^{\ell}[k_{\Delta+\ell}(z)k_{\Delta-\ell}(\bar{z})+(z\leftrightarrow \bar{z})]$.

These are the conformal blocks for four point functions of identical external scalars, for the general 2d case see http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1941. The conformal blocks for external scalars have a similar form in any even dimension (see also http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6194).